# Unable to log into Stack Overflow using OpenID

Tags: support, stack-overflow, openid

I navigated to https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?returnurl=/ and clicked on "click here to recover your account." I was sent to the [account recovery page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery), where I entered my e-mail.

Within a few seconds, I received mail from Stack Overflow confirming that I am a registered user and giving me an OpenID link. I clicked on the OpenID link and got a page that prompted me to enter the password for the OpenID account. I forgot my password!

So I clicked MyOpenID's account recovery link and got taken to [this page](https://www.myopenid.com/account_recover_initiate), where I was asked to enter my username or e-mail address. I entered my username / e-mail (the same e-mail which I entered to recover my password from Stack Overflow) but the system displayed the error message

> No Email Address for this Account
>   Unfortunately, it is impossible to recover your account without a registered email address.

How can I get my OpenID password? I am not able to access Stack Overflow with my regular account. Finally, I created a new account and started using Stack Overflow. Please help me access my [old account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/424017/banupriyavijay).

Answer (score 1):

Do you use more than one e-mail address? If so, did you register for SO and MyOpenID with different addresses? MyOpenID is not related to SO, it will not know if you used a different e-mail for SO. For the same reason, the SO admins cannot help you recover your MyOpenID password.

What you can do is e-mail `team@stackoverflow.com` and ask them to merge your two accounts, keeping your new OpenID. While this should be possible on a purely technical level, I don't know what you'll be required to do to prove that you're the owner of both accounts.

Comment: Thank you, I have mailed to SO team as you said, they have now merged my accounts.